# react native svg error child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function on upgrading react native from 68.1 to 70.6

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-svg

Thanks in advance

I received the below error when I tried to upgrade react native from 68.1 to 70.6.
I tried this in android.

I ran react-native run-android and everything went well.
Upon running the app the metro bundler started loading 99% and showed this error in red screen

```
error: node_modules/react-native-svg/src/elements/Shape.tsx: /Users/jarenk/Documents/myApp/node_modules/react-native-svg/src/elements/Shape.tsx: child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function
```

Can anybody help me on this.

Am using react native SVG and its version was old. I updated it to latest version too.
(13.6.0) but still its getting same error.

**Error In Detail (If I take Build)**

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

**I get following error**

```
error node_modules/react-native-svg/src/elements/Shape.tsx: /Users/jarenk/Documents/myApp/node_modules/react-native-svg/src/elements/Shape.tsx: child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function.
TypeError: /Users/jarenk/Documents/myApp/node_modules/react-native-svg/src/elements/Shape.tsx: child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function
    at /Users/jarenk/Documents/myApp/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-typescript/lib/index.js:361:89
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PluginPass.Class (/Users/jarenk/Documents/myApp/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-typescript/lib/index.js:353:31)
    at newFn (/Users/jarenk/Documents/myApp/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:171:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/jarenk/Documents/myApp/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/jarenk/Documents/myApp/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/jarenk/Documents/myApp/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:90:31)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/jarenk/Documents/myApp/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:110:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/jarenk/Documents/myApp/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:116:21)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Once again thank you.

Comment: maybe command
yarn add --dev @babel/types

will helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the `package.json` file helped me to resolve this.

just downgrade the babel versions like below

**Also make sure same below version are in `package-lock.json` file**

```
"@babel/core": "7.12.9",
"@babel/runtime": "7.12.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you need to delete the "node_modules" folder and run either
"`yarn install`" or
"`npm install`" command.
It is likely that you switched to a Git branch with a higher version of Babel, which is causing the problem.